# mongoDB: update nested array element

Tags: mongodb

I have the following datastructure

```
{
_id: ObjectId('61ae12bfb8047effd0ac2a01'),
data: [
    {
        xml: {
            messageId: 1638798015073,
            xmlString: 'someXML'
        },
        data: [
            {
                customerId: 123456,
                validation: {
                    isValid: true,
                    message: ''
                },
                docs: [
                    {
                        objectId: 'PA1106:zt:bb302216879669b58c141b12dcdd5eb0',
                        writtenBack: false
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                customerId: 55555,
                validation: {
                    isValid: true,
                    message: ''
                },
                docs: [
                    {
                        objectId: 'PA1106:zt:bb302216879669b58b143ef38c016217',
                        writtenBack: true
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        xml: {
            messageId: 1638798015094,
            xmlString: 'someXML'
        },
        data: [
            {
                customerId: 55555,
                validation: {
                    isValid: true,
                    message: ''
                },
                docs: [
                    {
                        objectId: 'PA1106:zt:bb302216879669b58c1416129062c2d2',
                        writtenBack: false
                    },
                    {
                        objectId: 'PA1106:zt:b8be9ea04011c2a18c148a0d4c9d6aab',
                        writtenBack: true
                    }
                ]
            },
        ]
    },
],
createdAt: '2021-12-06T13:40:15.096Z',
createdBy: 'Test'
}
```

Now I want to update the `writtenBack` property of for a given `Document` and `objectId`. How would I write a query for this?

my `updateOne` looked like this

```
            {
                _id: '61ae12bfb8047effd0ac2a01',
                'data.data.docs.objectId': 'PA1106:zt:bb302216879669b58b143ef38c016217'
            },

            {
                $set: { 'data.data.docs.$.writtenBack': true }
            }
```

I know there is `arrayFilters` for nested arrays, but as far as I know, I need a unique identifier for each array-Level. But I only have the objectId which is unique for a Document. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve the update for the document in the nested array with [positional operator `$[]`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#update-nested-arrays-in-conjunction-with----) and `arrayFilters`.

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: "61ae12bfb8047effd0ac2a01",
  
},
{
  $set: {
    "data.$.data.docs.$[doc].writtenBack": true
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "doc.objectId": "PA1106:zt:bb302216879669b58b143ef38c016217"
    }
  ]
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eouXXUPDMma)

Comment: Thank you. But this seems not to work. I get an error `The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query` . Any Ideas? Also how is it working without positional operator in the second data array?

Comment: Hi, I suspect that there is document with the field which is not an array when you try to access it with `$`. Would be better if you can provide the data for that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work with this query

```
            {
                _id: '61ae12bfb8047effd0ac2a01',
            },
            {
                $set: { 'data.$[elem1].data.$[elem2].docs.$[elem3].writtenBack': true }

            },
            {
                arrayFilters: [
                    { 'elem1.xml.messageId': 1638798015094 },
                    { 'elem2.customerId': 55555},
                    { 'elem3.objectId': 'PA1106:zt:bb302216879669b58c1416129062c2d2'}]
            }
```